# Number of iterations of scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs

Tags: python, scipy, eigenvalue, arpack

Is it possible to find out how many iterations it took eigs/eigsh to converge?

Comment: I haven't played with eigs myself, but certainly the documentation and examples give no hint that the iterations value is available.  This is in contrast to a number of other scipy functions like the root finders, so I assume (dangerous, I know) that it isn't easily available.

Comment: Thanks, Jon, I have the same feeling so far. Maybe it's the limitation of Arpack itself (I don't have any experience with that library).

Comment: The newer optimize.minimize function return objects, which include the function evaluations.  The devs seem to be updating things to object-oriented methods, so any refresh on eigs will likely also return an object.